# SQL Query to only select data with the maximum value of one of the column

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the following data, for the same Entity and Alias, I want to select only those with maximum BatchID

```
Entity    Alias      Par      BatchID
35273     1186944    375000   2019022201464730000  -> I want this selected
35273     1186944    375000   2019022123151930000  -> I want this selected
35273     167        27203051 2019022201464730000  
35273     167        20669929 2019022223351340000  -> I want this selected
35273     1949586    650000   2019022123151930000
35273     1949586    650000   2019022201464730000  -> I want this selected
35273     25255      18700    2019022123151930000  -> I want this selected
35273     25255      10700    2019022123151930000  -> I want this selected
```

This is what I want in the result:

```
Entity     Alias       Par        BatchID
35273      1186944     375000     2019022201464730000  
35273      1186944     375000     2019022123151930000
35273      167         20669929   2019022223351340000
35273      1949586     650000     2019022201464730000
35273      25255       18700      2019022123151930000
35273      25255       10700      2019022123151930000
```

The following query returns all records (instead of only 6).

The result of the below query: "latest" returns 1 for all the records

```
select * from
(select DENSE_RANK()  over (partition by ENTITY,ALIAS order by batchid desc) 
as latest,*
from test) x
where latest =1
```

How can I create the query to select only those with maximum BatchID ?

EDIT:
This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [Test](
   [Entity] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [Alias] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [Par] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [BatchID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Even this query returns all 1 for “latest”

```
select DENSE_RANK()  over (partition by ENTITY_ID,SECURITY_ALIAS order by 
batchid desc) as latest,*
from test
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your query should work.

Comment: Should not it be a `row_number` instead of `dense_rank`?

Comment: @AlexanderVolok no, he wants ties in the results if there are any.   I agree with Gordon, the posted query would work.   There must be something wrong with the poster's actual code that they aren't showing in their question.

Comment: I'm not sure if the result are you expecting is correct, Do the first two rows should have the same batchID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of speculation but your table has these columns defined as strings:

```
[Entity] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Alias] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

I think you have hidden characters in the strings.

Here are two methods to find them:

```
select entity
from test
where try_convert(int, entity) is null and entity is not null;
```

or:

```
select alias
from test
where alias like '%[^0-9]%'
```

My guess is that you will find hidden characters and this will explain why the dense rank is always "1".  Your partitions are not combining what look like `entity`/`alias` pairs because unseen characters mean the pairs are different.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I had a hidden character in the data. THank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. 
select Entity, Alias, Par, MAX(BatchID) FROM TABLE_NAME

Comment: Hi, you are all correct. It looks like i had a hidden character in column Alias. I retyped the value, and now the query works. THank you so much all !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the result you're expecting but you could try this:

```
Select Entity, Alias, max(BatchID)
FROM test T1
GROUP BY Entity, Alias
--HAVING COUNT(Entity) > 1 comment out this one if you want > 1 count rows
```